# Where is static_assert implemented?

Tags: c++11, type-traits

The way `static_assert` was [implemented](http://loki-lib.cvs.sourceforge.net/loki-lib/loki/include/loki/static_check.h?view=markup) in the [Loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/) library (where it was actually a pre-processor macro called `STATIC_CHECK`), it could be used as follows:

```
STATIC_CHECK(myCondition, My_Error_Message);
```

Note that `My_Error_Message` must be a valid identifier.

I am wondering how [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) is implemented for the `C++11` standard to take a string literal argument for the error message.

I decided to look into the `type_traits` include file, which is located in `/usr/include/c++/4.8` on my Ubuntu 14.04 with g++ 4.8.2. To my surprise, I found only usages of `static_assert` there, but not the definition (nor pre-processor macro). I did not find it in the files included from `type_traits` either.

So, where do I look for the implementation of `static_assert`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static_assert` is a new language-level feature in C++11, rather than a library included in a header file. A compliant C++ implementation is free to implement `static_assert` however it likes. It could be built into the compiler (I suspect most compilers do this), or it could be a part of a library (though this would be challenging, since `static_assert` doesn't require a header file). I think the best way to find out which it is for your particular compiler would be to check the documentation and, if necessary, to look over the source.

Answer (score 0):

`static_assert` has to inherently be built into the compiler because the condition your checking must be checked at compile-time. If it were to be checked with some library code, this would rather be done at runtime.

On the flip-side, `assert` is a macro, which already says it's implemented in library code, and its check is done at runtime.

Comment: It actually is possible in C++ to build libraries that check for conditions at compile time by using the template system (see the link from the OP's original question). Those libraries are pretty complicated, but it's still possible.

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg Causing a compilation error given a condition is pretty simple, with this condition evaluated at compile time. But, the message has to be included in the diagnostic which isn't straightforward or guaranteed to work across compilers.

Comment: But that is not what you wrote in the reply.